# How can I use tex to draw an ellipse with three arcs?

Tags: drawing

The picture is as follow, I hope it can be filling with colors and also with the numbers. The curvature of an arc matches to the ellipse. [image]

Comment: You could draw 4 ellipses and use `\clip` for 3 of them.

Comment: Can you show me the code, I have no ideas about the drawing using tex.

Comment: Do the arcs use the same curvatures as the outer ellipse (i.e. the same radii)? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, the same curvatures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `path picture`s makes this relatively straight-forward with TikZ. A path picture is basically a drawing you can put inside a path instead of (or in addition to) a filling. It will automatically clipped against the paths.

---

To reduce redundancy, I'm defining the style `ell = <fill> : <shifting> : <node content>`:

The `<shifting>` is controlled by the factor ⅟₃ inside `shift=(left:#2/3)` but also by the value specified here. I'm just using 0, 1, 2 and 3 but you can just adjust them when the distance between the ellipses should be smaller or bigger.

---

For the nodes with text we can tell TikZ that all `nodes` should be at `(0:5/6)` which would place them halfway between the right sides of ellipses (because 5/6 is 1 − ⅟₃/2 where ⅟₃ is the same factor as above).
This only works if you only use `0`, `1`, … for the `<shifting>` value. I chose `anchor=mid` so it looks better for lowercase text.
If we use `ell*` the node is placed in the middle of the remaining space.

---

We can also use the [`text along path` decoration](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.text) which will place each letter individually along the ellipse.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  calc,
  decorations.text} % only needed for second picture
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  x=3cm, y=2cm, radius=1, nodes={rotate=90, anchor=mid, at=(0:5/6)},
  ell*/.style={
    nodes={centered, at=($(path picture bounding box.west)!.5!(0:1)$)}, ell={#1}},
  ell/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{fill=#1, draw=black, shift=(left:#2/3),
                             insert path={circle[] node {#3}}}]
\path  [ell =gray!75!blue!30 : 0 : four, path picture={
  \path[ell =gray            : 1 : three];
  \path[ell =gray!50         : 2 : two];
  \path[ell*=gray!10         : 3 : one];
}];
\tikz[
  x=3cm, y=2cm, radius=1,
  text deco/.style={postaction=decorate, decoration={
      name=text along path, raise=.5ex, text align=center, text={#1}}},
  ell/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
    fill=#1, draw=black, shift=(left:#2/3), text deco={#3},
    insert path={(down:1) arc[start angle=-180, delta angle=360]}}]
\path  [ell=gray!75!blue!30 : 0 : four, path picture={
  \path[ell=gray            : 1 : three];
  \path[ell=gray!50         : 2 : two];
  \path[ell=gray!10         : 3 : one];
}];
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I want to replace 1 to one, how can I change it? I had a try, but wrong.

Comment: @Mengr It's the last `1` in `\path[ell=gray!10:3:1];`. That's the `<node content>` part of my description.

Comment: Right！What if I want to write the "one" in vertical? Like the picture I give

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  Last question: I want to move their position, like "one" in the middle of the first area.

Comment: @Mengr See my update. I've added the `calc` library for this. I didn't change the second diagram to do the same because it's not as easily possible as with the first one.

Comment: @Mengr, I suggest to spend some time on the pgfmanual https://tikz.dev/, or here in pdf: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf. The 4 tutorials are excellent, and already provide most you'll need for a good start. If you will draw more than this diagram, it will be time spent well.

Comment: Thank you all of you! @MS-SPO

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel What if I want all the text, like "two" in the middle of their areas?

Comment: @Mengr See update.

Comment: YES!! If I want to check the font information, how can I do? I only know the font information in my document  package : \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{dsfont}

Comment: @Mengr TikZ uses the same font as your document. Fonts are handled by LaTeX, PGF/TikZ doesn't intervene.

Comment: But How do I know the font information in my document?

Comment: @Mengr I don't what you mean. What does this have to do with this answer? If you load the `mathpazo` and the `dsfont` package the fonts of these package will be used.

Comment: Ok. Problem solved. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 4):

Just as a starting point, you could use TikZ to draw several ellipses and clip them:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray,draw=black] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2cm, y radius=1cm];
\begin{scope}
  \clip (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2cm, y radius=1cm];
  \fill[lightgray,draw=black] (-2,0) ellipse [x radius=2cm, y radius=1cm];
\end{scope}
\node at (-1,0) {1};
\node at (1,0) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mengr You're welcome!